# Where is libc.dylib located in macos Maverick 10.13.6

Tags: c, macos, dylib

I don't find libc.dylib in my computer, where should it be located and how I install it if not where it should be.

Comment: That's not a bad thing! If the other question answers your question, please keep yours around; that way, if somebody searched what you searched, they'll find this question and be pointed to that one.